# I'm getting "Bad argument setup" while running VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

I'm trying to run [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and I'm getting following error:

```
# /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
Bad argument setup
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
# uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 25 22:07:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -qa | grep ^VirtualBox
VirtualBox-5.0-5.0.14_105127_el7-1.x86_64
#
```

ERROR:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Advise please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it; instead of:

> sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

one should run

> sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup

desired output would be:

```
# sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [  OK  ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
#
```